# Como converter Json para Objeto onde o nome da coluna é um número variável usando HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, json

Tenho o seguinte Json:

```
{"video":{"duration":"23:16","views":"2358","video_id":"1235288","rating":"5.00","ratings":"3","title":"titulo do video","url":"urldovideo","default_thumb":"urlaqui","thumb":"outra url aqui","publish_date":"2015-08-26 23:00:34","tags":{"58":"tag1","320":"tag2","74":"tag3"}}}
```

Eu preciso converter para um Objeto, estou mapeando o objeto `video` para:

```
public class RootObject
{
  public Videointerto video { get; set; }
}
public class Videointerto
{
  public string duration { get; set; }
public string views { get; set; }
public string video_id { get; set; }
public string rating { get; set; }
public string ratings { get; set; }
public string title { get; set; }
public string url { get; set; }
public string default_thumb { get; set; }
public string thumb { get; set; }
public string publish_date { get; set; }
}
```

Funciona perfeitamente usando o seguinte código:

```
public static RootObject GetApiObject(string url)
        {

            HttpClient client;
            Uri usuarioUri;

            client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                var x = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>().Result;

                return x;

            }

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

O problema é quando chega no objeto `tags` que existe dentro de `video`.

No final do `Json` é possível ver que o objeto `tag` vem como se fosse um único objeto com varias propriedades. O que na verdade está errado, deveria vir um `array` de objetos `tag`...

```
"tags":{"58":"tag1","320":"tag2","74":"tag3"}}}
```

A nível de teste eu fiz uma evolução da classe `Videointerio` criando uma classe `Tag` da seguinte forma:

```
public class Tags
        {
            [JsonProperty("58")]
            public string Teste;

        }
```

Logico que dentro de `Video` eu coloquei uma propriedade `Tag` com nome de tags, quando ele converte ele coloca o valor `tag1` na propriedade `Test` da classe `Tag`.

Só que esse valor número é uma key do objeto no banco de dados da empresa que estou precisando pegar o Json.

Eu queria saber se é possível fazer alguma de duas coisas, ou fazer a parte `tags` do `Json` vir em uma string unica ou fazer ela vir como um `array` da classe `Tag` (se existir alguma forma de mapear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[O pacote JSON.NET faz isso por você](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

Exemplo:

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>().Result);
```

[A documentação está aqui](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm)

Comment: Então, eu já usei essa biblioteca, mas ela vai converter como a outra, ela não vai adivinhar q as tags são objetos diferentes, vai fazer igual a que eu coloquei na pergunta fez.

Comment: Mas aí você pode converter seu objeto dinâmico no que quiser.